# MVC RedirectToAction not working - getting "The resource cannot be found"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my UserController, I am issuing:

```
return RedirectToAction("SignOut", "SignIn");
```

but getting:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been
> removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and
> make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /SignIn/SignOut

The SignInController action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignOut()
{
    // Setting cache.
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

    // Setting cookies.
    // Instantiate a Cookie.
    HttpCookie Cookies = new HttpCookie("Gbng");
    Cookies.Value = "";
    Cookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(Cookies);

    HttpContext.Session.Clear();

    Session.Abandon();

    // Redirect to the Home controller.
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

---

I have a partial view that references the same action method but has the POST method:

```
@if ( (string)@Session["IsAuthenticated"] == "true" )
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("SignOut", "SignIn", FormMethod.Post, new { id = 
"signoffForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li>
               <a 
href="javascript:document.getElementById('signoffForm').submit()">Sign 
out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Register", 
routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sign in", "SignIn", "SignIn", routeValues: 
null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "signLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: I removed the [HttpPost] and replaced it with [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]. Now it finds it. I can combine the request method attributes as this action serves requests from multiple verbs.

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectToAction`, is performing a `HTTP GET`

Your `SignOut` method is decorated with `[HttpPost]`, and hence, it can not find the resource.

---

Since `SignOut` is a typical `post` action - i.e.; pressing a button and such, I would suggest to put the sign-out logic in a separate method and call it from where you want to use it. This means you don't need a redirect to perform the sign-off.

---

As from your comment; you can create a helper method to perform the task:

```
public class Helper
{
    public static void SignOut(System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState session,
                               HttpResponse response)
    {
        // Setting cache.
        response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
        response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        // Setting cookies.
        // Instantiate a Cookie.
        HttpCookie Cookies = new HttpCookie("Gbng");
        Cookies.Value = "";
        Cookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
        response.Cookies.Add(Cookies);

        session.Clear();

        session.Abandon();
    }
}
```

and call it in both functions, after that; you can redirect - I don't have a compiler at my disposal right now, but I think you can work out any inaccuracies.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignOut()
{
    Helper.SignOut(Response, Session);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OtherAction()
{
    Helper.SignOut(Response, Session);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: Stefan...my partial view states the Post method so I have my method decorated with it as such. So how do I tell the RedirectToAction it is a Post method? I tried putting [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)] below the [HttpPost] but it did nothing.

Comment: I removed the [HttpPost] and replaced it with [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]. Now it finds it.

Comment: Stefan...I actually have 2 controllers which do the redirect to the SignInController action method. So if I were to use your suggestion I would have to replicate that action method code in a global method.. So then I would have the same exact code in 2 places. Is that wise or just use decoration on the 1 place like I did?